# Pointer to the class instance

Tags: c++, class, pointers, hyperlink, function-pointers

I hane got a class inserted into the namespace:

```
namespace CPGL
{
    class Application;
}

class Application
{
    public:

        Application()
        {
            ...
        }
};
```

When I tryed to create a pointer this class like this:

```
CPGL::Application application();
CPGL::Application* app = &application;
```

Strange and mysterious things are started to happen. Here is the compilation log:

```
error: cannot convert ‘CPGL::Application (*)()’ to ‘CPGL::Application*’ in initialization
CPGL::Application* app = &application;
```

The question is how does a link to the class turned to a pointer to the constructor function of this class and how to solve it?

Comment: Look up the most vexing parse. :)

Comment: In the code you show you have *two different* classes, `CPGL::Application` and `::Application`. It's important that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CPGL::Application application();` is a function declaration, hence the compiler diagnostic shows `CPGL::Application (*)()`,

```
CPGL::Application application();
CPGL::Application* app = &application;
```

The expression `&application` is here a function pointer. This mistake is sometimes (incorrectly) referred to as [*The most vexing parse*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

What you probably intended was

```
CPGL::Application application;
CPGL::Application* app = &application;
```

Also note that your namespace declares a class `Application` but it is defined outside the namespace. This may or may not be a typo in the question.

I prefer to not describe this as a *Most vexing parse* because there is no syntax rule that would reasonably allow this as a call to the constructor. `type name();` is a function declaration, period.  `A a(object of type B)` is however the correct way call the constructor `A::A(B b)`. So it is reasonable to think that `A a(B())` creates an object of type B as the argument to A ctor. The compiler instead parses it as a type. This is discussed in the linked SO answer.

Comment: The "(incorrectly)" makes me curious. According to Wikipedia [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) is the term for _syntactic ambiguity resolution_ which may not match the expectation/intention of the human writer. (Though, even Wikipedia may fail.)

Comment: @Scheff I've amended the answer a bit.

Comment: So, you think there isn't such ambiguity for `A a()` as there isn't a resp. (concurrent) grammar rule for constructors which must be dis-ambiguated? Once, I become a pensioner I will read the C++ grammar in detail and check this out. (I add this to the list of things which I will do once I've the time...)

Comment: @Scheff that is my thinking, yes.